# C# call method of DLL that displays UI

Tags: c#, service, windows-services

In a Windows Service, I'm trying to use a method from an external DLL that displays a UI (it doesn't request any user input). I read that you can't interact with the UI from a Windows Service (since Vista), because it runs in a different session than the user (which is the only one who can interact with the UI). But it is posible to start an interactive process from a service, as shown in [this article](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/35773/Subverting-Vista-UAC-in-Both-and-bit-Archite), I tested it and it works.

So I thought that maybe I can call the method of that DLL in a similar way, by using the session of the active user, and then get the returned data back on the service... any guide or example of how to do this?

I also tried checking the "Allow system to interact with desktop" option on the "Log On" tab of the installed service and starting the service with the user account of the currently logged in user, but it didn't work, it doesn't show any error, but it should display a window and it's not showing anything.

Comment: Could you give us an example of what you tried?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot just call UI from windows service as it's running in the 0 session. For calling UI you need to change session to your current user's session. Here is link how you can do it

https://www.codeproject.com/kb/vista-security/subvertingvistauac.aspx

Comment: Already did that, it opens an application (cmd.exe). I need to call a method that displays a UI and returns a string. I should be able to call that method in a similar way, with the access token of the winlogon.exe process.

Answer (score 0):

You have read already and know about how service session(0) doesn't allow you to invoke anything on UI that as it run on different session. 
I once used an API wrapper around PInvoke and It has a method called 'CreateProcessAsUser'. What it does is, it gets the token of current logging user session and launch a process using that session. In order to launch the process there should be an active desktop session running.

Here's the complete code for that:https://gist.github.com/vendettamit/a518bceef3678963c5fd

It's kinda hack but it also a great work around. You can launch your third party method via your own process wrapper.

Comment: Yes, what I don't know is how to substitute the 'CreateProcessAsUser' for a methods that allows me to load an assembly and call one of its method as another user.

Comment: For that you need to create your own exe that will do that for you. Once that exe is launched in user session you can do all the things of a normal application as you always do.

Comment: I tried to do that, but when the .exe is runned by the service, it is running under the session ID of the currently logged in user (that part is ok), and under the user SYSTEM, instead of the currently logged in user... I guess that's why I can't call the methods from those DLLs that display some UI.

Answer (score 0):

Usually windows service cannot interact with the UI because UI will be running under user session and the service will be running under system. so you need to perform the impersonation and launch the Application.

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;


[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
internal struct PROCESS_INFORMATION
{
    public IntPtr hProcess;
    public IntPtr hThread;
    public uint dwProcessId;
    public uint dwThreadId;
 }



 [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
 internal struct SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES
 {
    public uint nLength;
    public IntPtr lpSecurityDescriptor;
    public bool bInheritHandle;
  }


  [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
  public struct STARTUPINFO
  {
      public uint cb;
      public string lpReserved;
      public string lpDesktop;
      public string lpTitle;
      public uint dwX;
      public uint dwY;
      public uint dwXSize;
      public uint dwYSize;
      public uint dwXCountChars;
      public uint dwYCountChars;
      public uint dwFillAttribute;
      public uint dwFlags;
      public short wShowWindow;
      public short cbReserved2;
      public IntPtr lpReserved2;
      public IntPtr hStdInput;
      public IntPtr hStdOutput;
      public IntPtr hStdError;

  }

   internal enum SECURITY_IMPERSONATION_LEVEL
   {
       SecurityAnonymous,
       SecurityIdentification,
       SecurityImpersonation,
       SecurityDelegation
    }

    internal enum TOKEN_TYPE
    {
         TokenPrimary = 1,
         TokenImpersonation
     }

 public class ProcessAsUser
 {

[DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
private static extern bool CreateProcessAsUser(
    IntPtr hToken,
    string lpApplicationName,
    string lpCommandLine,
    ref SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpProcessAttributes,
    ref SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpThreadAttributes,
    bool bInheritHandles,
    uint dwCreationFlags,
    IntPtr lpEnvironment,
    string lpCurrentDirectory,
    ref STARTUPINFO lpStartupInfo,
    out PROCESS_INFORMATION lpProcessInformation);


[DllImport("advapi32.dll", EntryPoint = "DuplicateTokenEx", SetLastError = true)]
private static extern bool DuplicateTokenEx(
    IntPtr hExistingToken,
    uint dwDesiredAccess,
    ref SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpThreadAttributes,
    Int32 ImpersonationLevel,
    Int32 dwTokenType,
    ref IntPtr phNewToken);


[DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
private static extern bool OpenProcessToken(
    IntPtr ProcessHandle,
    UInt32 DesiredAccess,
    ref IntPtr TokenHandle);

[DllImport("userenv.dll", SetLastError = true)]
private static extern bool CreateEnvironmentBlock(
        ref IntPtr lpEnvironment,
        IntPtr hToken,
        bool bInherit);


[DllImport("userenv.dll", SetLastError = true)]
private static extern bool DestroyEnvironmentBlock(
        IntPtr lpEnvironment);

[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
private static extern bool CloseHandle(
    IntPtr hObject);

private const short SW_SHOW = 5;
private const uint TOKEN_QUERY = 0x0008;
private const uint TOKEN_DUPLICATE = 0x0002;
private const uint TOKEN_ASSIGN_PRIMARY = 0x0001;
private const int GENERIC_ALL_ACCESS = 0x10000000;
private const int STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW = 0x00000001;
private const int STARTF_FORCEONFEEDBACK = 0x00000040;
private const uint CREATE_UNICODE_ENVIRONMENT = 0x00000400;


private static bool LaunchProcessAsUser(string cmdLine, IntPtr token, IntPtr envBlock)
{
    bool result = false;


    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi = new PROCESS_INFORMATION();
    SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES saProcess = new SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES();
    SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES saThread = new SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES();
    saProcess.nLength = (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(saProcess);
    saThread.nLength = (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(saThread);

    STARTUPINFO si = new STARTUPINFO();
    si.cb = (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(si);


    //if this member is NULL, the new process inherits the desktop 
    //and window station of its parent process. If this member is 
    //an empty string, the process does not inherit the desktop and 
    //window station of its parent process; instead, the system 
    //determines if a new desktop and window station need to be created. 
    //If the impersonated user already has a desktop, the system uses the 
    //existing desktop. 

    si.lpDesktop = @"WinSta0\Default"; //Modify as needed 
    si.dwFlags = STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW | STARTF_FORCEONFEEDBACK;
    si.wShowWindow = SW_SHOW;
    //Set other si properties as required. 

    result = CreateProcessAsUser(
        token,
        null,
        cmdLine,
        ref saProcess,
        ref saThread,
        false,
        CREATE_UNICODE_ENVIRONMENT,
        envBlock,
        null,
        ref si,
        out pi);


    if (result == false)
    {
        int error = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
        string message = String.Format("CreateProcessAsUser Error: {0}", error);
        Debug.WriteLine(message);

    }

    return result;
}


private static IntPtr GetPrimaryToken(int processId)
{
    IntPtr token = IntPtr.Zero;
    IntPtr primaryToken = IntPtr.Zero;
    bool retVal = false;
    Process p = null;

    try
    {
        p = Process.GetProcessById(processId);
    }

    catch (ArgumentException)
    {

        string details = String.Format("ProcessID {0} Not Available", processId);
        Debug.WriteLine(details);
        throw;
    }


    //Gets impersonation token 
    retVal = OpenProcessToken(p.Handle, TOKEN_DUPLICATE, ref token);
    if (retVal == true)
    {

        SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES sa = new SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES();
        sa.nLength = (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(sa);

        //Convert the impersonation token into Primary token 
        retVal = DuplicateTokenEx(
            token,
            TOKEN_ASSIGN_PRIMARY | TOKEN_DUPLICATE | TOKEN_QUERY,
            ref sa,
            (int)SECURITY_IMPERSONATION_LEVEL.SecurityIdentification,
            (int)TOKEN_TYPE.TokenPrimary,
            ref primaryToken);

        //Close the Token that was previously opened. 
        CloseHandle(token);
        if (retVal == false)
        {
            string message = String.Format("DuplicateTokenEx Error: {0}", Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
            Debug.WriteLine(message);
        }

    }

    else
    {

        string message = String.Format("OpenProcessToken Error: {0}", Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
        Debug.WriteLine(message);

    }

    //We'll Close this token after it is used. 
    return primaryToken;

}

private static IntPtr GetEnvironmentBlock(IntPtr token)
{

    IntPtr envBlock = IntPtr.Zero;
    bool retVal = CreateEnvironmentBlock(ref envBlock, token, false);
    if (retVal == false)
    {

        //Environment Block, things like common paths to My Documents etc. 
        //Will not be created if "false" 
        //It should not adversley affect CreateProcessAsUser. 

        string message = String.Format("CreateEnvironmentBlock Error: {0}", Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
        Debug.WriteLine(message);

    }
    return envBlock;
}

public static bool Launch(string appCmdLine /*,int processId*/)
{

    bool ret = false;

    //Either specify the processID explicitly 
    //Or try to get it from a process owned by the user. 
    //In this case assuming there is only one explorer.exe 

    Process[] ps = Process.GetProcessesByName("explorer");
    int processId = -1;//=processId 
    if (ps.Length > 0)
    {
        processId = ps[0].Id;
    }

    if (processId > 1)
    {
        IntPtr token = GetPrimaryToken(processId);

        if (token != IntPtr.Zero)
        {

            IntPtr envBlock = GetEnvironmentBlock(token);
            ret = LaunchProcessAsUser(appCmdLine, token, envBlock);
            if (envBlock != IntPtr.Zero)
                DestroyEnvironmentBlock(envBlock);

            CloseHandle(token);
        }

    }
    return ret;
}
}
```